# SQL Server replication additional subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a publisher with the distributor on the same server which is transactional replication.
There is also an active subscriber using push method.

I need to set a new subscriber up going to a different server using the same articles as the current subscriber I have. The database is huge and cannot be taken offline so I was going to do an initialize from backup instead of a new snapshot.

If I execute `exec sp_addsubscription` on the publisher do I still need to run the command `exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent` as well?
Will this create 2 distribution agents on the publisher or can only 1 be used.

Also will any more agents be created adding this extra subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

Every subscriber needs it's own distribution agent.

With transactional replication, there are three different types of agents involved, and each type of agent has a different "scope".

- **Log Reader Agent** -- One per published(replicated) database -- This agent reads the transaction log, and inserts commands for replication into the distribution database.

  - If you create the first publication in a database, you will need to set up a new log reader agent.
- **Snapshot Agent** -- One per publication -- This agent creates the initial snapshot used to initialize new subscribers.

  - If you create a new publication, you will need to set up a new Snapshot Agent.
- **Distribution Agent** -- One per subscriber/publication combination -- This agent delivers replication commands from the distribution database to the subscriber database.

  - If you create a new subscription, you will need to set up a new Distribution Agent.

So, if you have *one* published database, with *two* publications, and each publication has *two* subscriptions, then you'll have a total of *four* distribution agents.  Even if there is overlap in having multiple subscriptions go into the same database--that doesn't change the number of distribution agents.

So yes, create a new distribution agent, but you won't need to create any additional agents, since it is not a new publication.

Answer (score 1):

> The database is huge and cannot be taken offline so I was going to do an initialize from backup instead of a new snapshot.

While initialize from backup is appropriate for this scenario, it's not strictly necessary.  You can create the replication snapshot from a [Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) which uses copy-on-write sparse files to create a point-in-time consistent view of a database with no locking or blocking on the source database.  To do this specify "database snapshot" as the `@sync_method` of [sp_add_publication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addpublication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Initialization from a snapshot is required if the subscribers have tables other than those replicated from the publisher as re-initializing from a backup would wipe those out.

Answer (score 0):

> If I execute exec `sp_addsubscription` on the publisher do I still need to run the command `exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent` as well?

Yes, you need to execute the `sp_addpushsubscription_agent` right after `sp_addsubscription`. if not, you will not be able to replicate the data to your new subscriber db.

1. `sp_addsubscription` will only add the new subscription on your existing
   publication.
2. `sp_addpushsubscription_agent` will create a new distribution agent job for your new subscription.

> The database is huge and cannot be taken offline so I was going to do an initialize from backup instead of a new snapshot.

You can add the new big subscriber db to the existing publication without doing the re-initialization (by `initialize from lsn`). Check the [replication blog post of Jonathan Kehayias](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/upgrading-migrating-large-replicated-databases-without-reinitializing/). Even though the blog post was for migration/upgrade, it can also be use for adding a new subscription to the existing publication. **Make sure to test in lower environment before doing it in production.**